# I am getting "django.db.utils.InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block" error in Django rest API

Tags: postgresql, django-rest-framework, django-signals, django-multitenant

I have created an API to register a shop. And after registering a shop, I tried to create an another Model object using post save signal. I am using "transaction.atomic()" as I have to create multiple model objects. While creating an object from signal I am getting

```
django.db.utils.InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

error.

Here is my code:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """This method uses atomic transaction, if an event gets
        any error, whole transaction will be reversed."""
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                data = request.data
                name = data.get("name")
                serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
                serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
                new_schema_name = ShopCreateView.get_schema_name(data['name'])
                serializer.save(schema_name=new_schema_name)
                tenant = Client.objects.get(id=serializer.data['id'])
                self.create_domain(tenant, new_schema_name)

                username = f"{name}_admin"
                email = data.get("business_email")
                password = "password"
                # Create the superuser object for the tenant
                print(email)
                self.create_superuser_for_tenant(tenant, username, email, password)
        except Exception as exc:
            return Response({"msg":str(exc)},status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

This is my views that is used to create a shop. Here I have used transaction.atomic() to manage the database consistency in case of error.
And,

```
@receiver(post_schema_sync, sender=TenantMixin)
def create_shop_settings(sender, tenant, **kwargs):
    with schema_context(tenant.schema_name):
        ShopPreferenceModel.objects.create()
```

is my signal that is triggered when new tenant is migrated.
Can anybody help me, why this error occurs.

Comment: This error is cause by a previous error which was not properly dealt with.  Look earlier in the log file to see what that error was.